# initialize a pointer in a class with constructor

Tags: c++, class, pointers, constructor

I have an `Album` class in "album.h" like this:

```
#include "song.h"

class Album
{
public:
Album(string _id, string _title, string _singer, float _price, vector<Song> _songs) : id(_id), title(_title), singer(_singer), price(_price), songs(_songs), availableAlbums(10) {}
void add_song(Song s){ songs.push_back(s); }
void add_availableAlbums(int added){ availableAlbums += added; }
string get_id(){ return id; }
string get_singer(){return singer;}

private:
string id;
string title;
string singer;
float price;
vector <Song> songs;
int availableAlbums;
};
```

and a `Song` class in "song.h" like this:

```
#include "album.h"

class Song
{
public:
Song(string _numOfSong, string _title, string _singer, string _duration, float _price): 
numOfSong(_numOfSong), title(_title), singer(_singer), duration(_duration), price(_price){}

private:
string numOfSong;
string title;
string singer;
string duration;
float price;
Album* album;
};
```

we know that every `Song` has an `Album` ( every `Song` must point to its `Album`) and i do that by initialize one `Album*` for every `Song` and i have some errors that are here:

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Album'
error C2065: '_album' : undeclared identifier
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
error C2614: 'Song' : illegal member initialization: 'album' is not a base or member
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

thanks

Comment: I am not sure I see what the problem is. Try this. Although I would use a smart pointer for this.

Comment: _"how can I make every Song to point to its Album?"_ Depends on how you're instatiating your `Song` instances in class `Album`, most probably you pass a `this` pointer there.

Comment: Forward declare Album in Song.h before your class declaration. `class Album;`

Comment: @mama23n Now (with the updated code) you have a circular include. Also you are not using include guards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `Song` class has an constructor that takes a pointer to the `Album` class so assume that you have the following code:

```
Album* album = new Album();
Song song = new Song(album);
```

In the first line you create a new album and in the second line you create a new song with the recently created album.

```
Album* album1 = song->album; // This is how you can access song's album
```

But, be aware that whenever you use `new` to create an object you should use `delete` keyword when you finished working with that object to free the memory used for that object.

So, there is no problem in your code or at least I can't find any.

Comment: Nice effort, but I would not *ever* recommend using `new` and `delete` at all, but `shared_ptr` and `make_shared` or their `unique` equivalents instead.

Comment: yes. you are right but I'm asking for how to pass album to constructor because fourth line of Song class have error and I don't know what is that for.

Comment: @mama23n We can't help you if you do not provide enough information, tell us what error do you get.

Comment: @Shahriyar I do that

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct, you just have to make sure that the `Album` instance exists during the lifetime of the `Song` instances.
If the `Song::album` pointer does not get changed, it might be more clean to use a reference instead. This means that `album` cannot be made to point to another album after construction.

```
class Song {
public:
    Song(Album& _album) : album(_album) { }
private:
    Album& album;
}
```

But then the `Song` cannot be assigned by the default `operator=`. It would need to be overloaded to check if the other `Song`'s album is the same, and only assign the other attributes.

If the `Song` does not modify the `Album` object, const-correctness can be enforced by using instead `const Album*` (or `const Album&`) both as the member variable type and construction argument.

If the lifetime of the `Album` object is not manually controlled, you could use `std::shared_ptr<Album>`.

Comment: but it has error in fourth line of Song class (in Song constructor), and I don't know what to do...

Comment: @mama23n What error? Please edit your question to include the exact error you get along with some context. With the information that you have given we have to play a guess the problem game..

Comment: @drescherjm I do that

Comment: fixed the error in this reply